# How does a class instance get constructed when inheriting a constructor from a base class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Say I have this code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::literals;

struct A {
    A(std::string) { };
};

struct B : A {  };
```

And then construct objects like this:

```
A a("foo");
B b("foo"s);    // fails in clang
B c(A("foo"));  // fails in clang
B d("foo");     // fails in clang + gcc
B e({"foo"});   // fails in clang

A f{"foo"};
B g{"foo"s};
B h{A{"foo"}};
B i{"foo"};     // fails in clang + gcc
B j{{"foo"}};
```

How are `a`, `b`, `c`, ... actually constructed? What conversion, initialization method, constructor actually gets called? And why does it fail?

Comment: @273K I don't want to make more fail. I want to know how it works. How is it copy constructing `std::string` -> `B`? A `std::string` is not a `B`. Something else has to happen (first).

Comment: @user4581301 Where would there be slicing? I'm not assigning a derived object to a base class.

Comment: Yep Got `A` and `B` reversed in my head. Shutting up now.

Comment: All 3 fail by me https://godbolt.org/z/YEx7azcnP And `using std::literals;` does not compile. It seems that code is far from a [mcve].

Comment: @273K Interesting. Works with `gcc -std=c++20` but fails with `clang -std=c++20`. That raises the question: which compiler is right? Fixed the missing `namespace`. https://godbolt.org/z/h6h1fhTh1

Comment: `gcc -std=c++17` is also failing. `gcc -std=c++20 -ansi` is also failing. So, I assume it is some of new gcc extensions.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The difference between GCC and Clang here is the fact that you're using `()` to initialize an aggregate, which is a C++20 feature, that Clang doesn't support yet. However, that seems tangential to your question, so I suggest using `{}` to initialize the variables. That way, all compilers show the same behavior described in the question, and doesn't need C++20 to compile. Also, are you sure you're looking for a [language-lawyer] answer?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization says an aggregate has *no user-declared or inherited constructors*. `B` inherits a user-declared constructor from `A` so it's not an aggregate. But `is_aggregate<B>() == true` in gcc.

Comment: Constructors are not inherited automatically, so while `A` is not an aggregate type due to the user-defined constructor, `B` actually is an aggregate type https://godbolt.org/z/87M4EM1M4

Comment: @cigien Ok, that makes sense. Both gcc and clang agree that `B` is an aggregate. And with `{}` both will do aggregate initialization. That means `b` will call the user-defined constructor `A(std::string)` and `c` calls the copy constructor `A(const A&)`. But for the implicit `const char *` -> `std::string` that happens for `a` to happen for `d` I have to write `B d{{"foo"}};` so `B::A` gets initialized with initializer-list. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. Regardless, I'd suggest changing the initialization in your question to use `{}`. Then you can also mention the question in your previous comment (i.e. whether `{{}}` does what you think). It's better to have a clean question that can get answers, instead of having the answer in comments, which can get deleted at any time.

Answer (score 1):

cigien pointed out that `B` doesn't automatically inherit any constructor from `A` and is an aggregate type. So aggregate initialization happens for `B`. And aggregate initialization with `()` is a c++20 feature that clang does not yet support. That explains all the differences between gcc and clang.

- `a` and `f` do an implicit conversion from `const char *` to `std::string` before calling `A(std::string)`.
- `b` and `g` call `A(std::string)` during aggregate initialization
- `c` and `h` call `A(const A&)` during aggregate initialization
- `d` and `i` fail to find a `const char *` -> `A` conversion for aggregate initialization
- `e` and `h` call `A(const std::initializer_list &)` which in turn uses `A(std::string)` to initialize the `B::A`

`d` and `i` bugs me. Feels inconsistent. If I can construct `A` from `const char *` then why not there? But that's C++.

Comment: I think this is related to the fact that your constructor is not declared `explicit` and thus compiler is allowed to make only [one implicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/121163) to resolve the argument, not two conversions.

Comment: @heapunderrun explicit would reduce that to 0 implicit conversions. I don't think there is anything to extend this to 2.